# Custom XMLSerializer

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlserializer

I have a set of classes for messages, that contains various sub-classes that represent required data for a specific type of message. When I deserialize a string into a message object, the object will still be created with null required properties, if the inner XML contains invalid. I would like it to throw an exception.

Here's some samples:

```
<Serializable>
<XmlRoot("INTERFACE")>
Public Class WM_Interface_ISHP
    Inherits WM_Interface

    Private m_Shipments As List(Of WM_Shipment)

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="SHIPMENT", IsNullable:=False)>
    Public Property Shipments() As List(Of WM_Shipment)
        Get
            Return m_Shipments
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of WM_Shipment))
            m_Shipments = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
<Serializable>
Public Class WM_Shipment
    Private m_Ship_ID As String
    Private m_Shipment_Type_CI As String
    Private m_Exp_Ship_DT_CI As String
    Private m_FDD_Flg_CI As String
    Private m_Ship_Lines As List(Of WM_Ship_Line)

    <XmlAttribute("SHIP_ID")>
    Public Property Ship_ID() As String
        Get
            Return m_Ship_ID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Ship_ID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlAttribute("SHIPMENT_TYPE_CI")>
    Public Property Shipment_Type_CI() As String
        Get
            Return m_Shipment_Type_CI
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Shipment_Type_CI = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlAttribute("EXP_SHIP_DT_CI")>
    Public Property Exp_Ship_DT_CI() As String
        Get
            Return m_Exp_Ship_DT_CI
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Exp_Ship_DT_CI = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlAttribute("FDD_FLG_CI")>
    Public Property FDD_Flg_CI() As String
        Get
            Return m_FDD_Flg_CI
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_FDD_Flg_CI = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="SHIP_LINE", IsNullable:=False)>
    Public Property Ship_Lines() As List(Of WM_Ship_Line)
        Get
            Return m_Ship_Lines
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of WM_Ship_Line))
            m_Ship_Lines = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I have see a couple of suggestions, but they don't work for me:

1. Data Contract Serializer - Unfortunately I need to be able to control whether something is an Attribute or an element during serialization, so this is no good.
2. Use a function that uses reflection after the object is deserialized to check if `isNullable:= False` is marked and if it is null. If so, throw an exception. Unfortunately, this only works if it is a top level required property that is null.

My code so far is:

```
Public Shared Function ValidatingDeserializer(Of T)(s As Stream) As T
    Dim deserialize As T = DirectCast(New XmlSerializer(GetType(T)).Deserialize(s), T)

    For Each pi As PropertyInfo In GetType(T).GetProperties()
        Dim xmlNull As Attribute = pi.GetCustomAttribute(GetType(XmlElementAttribute))
        If xmlNull IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim xmlNullInst As XmlElementAttribute = DirectCast(xmlNull, XmlElementAttribute)
            If xmlNullInst.IsNullable = False And IsNothing(pi.GetValue(deserialize)) = True Then
                Throw New Exception(String.Format("XML Deserialization Error, Message = {0} can't be null.", pi.Name))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return deserialize
End Function
```

In my example, if no shipments are defined, the exception should be (and is) triggered. But if there is a `shipment`, but no `ship_lines`, then the exception should be triggered, but isn't.

I would rather not use XSD unless I absolutely have to. I would like to maybe create a custom `XMlSerializer` that is based on `XMLSerializer`, but adds a new "Required" property to `XMLElement` and `XMLAttribute`. Then, when I deserialize it, it would throw an exception based on the decorated property value.

Comment: XSD validation would be what I'd do...what's your objection?

Comment: What happens if you add `Order:=n` to your XmlElement decorations and the required element is missing?

Comment: Still same problem.  It seems to think its fine to have a Shipment with no Ship_Lines.

Comment: In your Q you said, "...if there is a shipment, but no ship_lines, then the exception **should not** be triggered." Clarify?

Comment: Somebody thought they would be helpful and edit my post, but they got that wrong.  Originally it was right. I have edited it back to be correct. The exception SHOULD trigger if there are no ship_lines, but it isn't.

Comment: XMLSerializer has some events for unknown nodes when it encounters irregularities...have you tried to see if those help you?